# Uploading a generated PDF to Google Drive

Tags: google-app-engine, pdf, google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I have a GAE application where the user can generate a PDF. The document is generated client side via jsPDF. I'm trying to find a way to upload the generated document to Google Drive via the Python Drive API.

The problem is that when the PDF is generated it's also automatically downloaded to the user's PC and therefore I do not have access to the file and cannot upload it to Drive. I'm currently trying to save it to Google Cloud Storage first, but the PDF seems to always be ruined (cannot be opened) when it's uploaded to GCS.

This is how I get the 'raw' data from the generated PDF:

```
var pdfOut=doc.output();
```

Then I try to write that data into a pdf file on GCS:

```
function insertObject(content) {
        const boundary = '-------314159265358979323846';
        const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
        const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";

          var contentType = 'application/pdf';
          var metadata = {
            'name': 'testUpload.pdf',
            'mimeType': contentType
          };

          var base64Data = btoa(content);
          var multipartRequestBody =
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n' +
            JSON.stringify(metadata) +
            delimiter +
            'Content-Type: ' + contentType + '\r\n' +
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n' +
            '\r\n' +
            base64Data +
            close_delim;

          var request = gapi.client.request({
            'path': '/upload/storage/' + 'v1' + '/b/' + BUCKET + '/o',
            'method': 'POST',
            'params': {'uploadType': 'multipart'},
            'headers': {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed; boundary="' + boundary       + '"'
            },
            'body': multipartRequestBody});

          try{
            //Execute the insert object request
            executeRequest(request, 'insertObject');
            //Store the name of the inserted object       
          }
          catch(e) {
            alert('An error has occurred: ' + e.message);
          }

      }
```

This code is taken directly from Google's examples.

Is this the correct way to do it? If yes, what should I do to not 'destroy' the PDF in the process? Or are there any other ways of solving it?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Apparently the PDF was uploaded to GCS correctly after all. There was an issue in the browser which caused it to not open correctly.

However, it seems the Python Google Drive API cannot upload files from URLs, so this approach cannot be used anyway.

Any ideas what I should try ?

Comment: To avoid the API limitation you will have to create a local copy first or build an in memory stream.

Comment: I already have a local copy, because the PDF is downloaded right after it's generated. However, I'm having trouble finding a way for uploading local files to drive. I'm a bit lost in the API at the moment. Any additional tips? Thanks!

Comment: The manual multi-part upload seems to be fraught with difficulties. Have you looked into the [GCS client library](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/using-cloud-storage)?